# How would I join two threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

When I join a thread the first thread needs to first run and then the second thrads runs is this correct? and if so how do I join the two threads in the Main methods?

```
public class SynchronizedThreads implements Runnable {
    Thread t;

    public SynchronizedThreads() {
        t = new Thread(this, "Synched Thread");
        t.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                t.sleep(1000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
}

public class StartSynchronizedThreads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SynchronizedThreads x = new SynchronizedThreads();
        SynchronizedThreads y = new SynchronizedThreads();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for the documentation for the `Thread.join()` method?

Comment: Starting a thread in an object constructor is not a good pattern because of object constructor race conditions.

Comment: No I have the documentation, I'm trying to find how to join the two threads from the x and y objects that are in the main method.

Comment: You need to call `t.join()`.  If `t` is a field in your `SynchronizedThreads` class then you could add a `join()` method to `SynchronizedThreads` that calls through to `t.join()`.

Comment: @Gray How should I start the thread than?

Comment: You could add a `start()` method to `SynchronizedThreads` that calls through to `t.start()`.

Comment: I think you are confusing objects and their encapsulation with threads of execution, which have nothing to do with either. That is why your design is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    x.t.join();
    y.t.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
}
```